# Why Hibernate HSQL Concat is not working for MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, concatenation

So, I have Hibernate 5.3.1 in a project which connects to different enginees (MySql, Oracle, PostgreSQL and MS SQL), so I can't use native queries.

Let's say I have 3 records in a table, which all of them have the same datetime, but I need to group them **only by date** (not time). **For example, 2019-12-04**;

I execute this query:

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(year(tx.date_), month(tx.date_), day(tx.date_)),
 iss.code,
 COUNT(tx.id) 
FROM 
 tx_ tx 
JOIN 
 issuer_ iss 
ON 
 tx.id_issuer = iss.id  
GROUP BY 
 CONCAT(year(tx.date_), month(tx.date_), day(tx.date_)), iss.code
```

But, when I test it connected to SQL SERVER 2017, instead of return **20191204**, it's returning **2035**. In Oracle and MySQL is working fine.

Anyone has any idea why is this happen? I've tried different ways, like use **+** instead of **CONCAT** but the result is the same.

I've also tried to extract them for separate (without concat), and they have been returning correct. The problem is, I need to group them by the complete date.

And just for the record, **the field is declared as datetime2** in DDBB

Comment: 2035 = 2019 + 12 + 4. That should give you a hint :). You show a HSQL query, but that's not the *SQL* query Hibernate generates for Sql Server.

Comment: Lol, that's an amazing effect.  Sql Server and Sybase are the only(?) RDBMS that use `+` for addition AND concatination.  Maybe it's related to that?

Comment: Isn't there a HSQL "function" that can _cast_ a timestamp (datetime) to a plain "DATE"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HSQL/Hibernate, but isn't there some provider compatibility setting that affects the SQL query generation engine? Sql Server only has the `CONCAT` statement since 2012. Maybe if you could tell Hibernate to translate for that minimum version the query would be generated as expected (using `CONCAT` in SQL).

Comment: I thought it had a TRUNC to cut of the time part.  But unsure if that's only for oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the hint [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) gave me. I just didn't realize that the query was adding like if they were numbers in MSSQL.

Finally, I manage to make it work in the 4 RDBMS casting to string first

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(CAST(year(tx.date_) AS string), CAST(month(tx.date_) AS string), CAST(day(tx.date_) AS string)),
 iss.code 
FROM 
 tx_ tx 
JOIN 
 issuer_ iss 
ON 
 tx.id_issuer = iss.id  
GROUP BY 
 CONCAT(year(tx.date_), month(tx.date_), day(tx.date_)), iss.code
```

I tried also **casting to TEXT**, but it throws exception in MySQL

Answer (score 3):

How about simply adding them, instead of using `CONCAT`.

```
(year(tx.date_)*10000 + month(tx.date_)*100 + day(tx.date_)*1) AS datenum
```

Thus, try this:

```
SELECT 
 CAST((year(tx.date_)*10000 + month(tx.date_)*100 + day(tx.date_)*1) AS string) AS datenum, 
 iss.code 
FROM tx_ tx 
JOIN issuer_ iss 
ON tx.id_issuer = iss.id  
GROUP BY year(tx.date_), month(tx.date_), day(tx.date_), iss.code
```

Comment: This is probably the best provider-agnostic solution.

Comment: To be honest, I'm kinda surprised that a CONCAT with more than 2 values would even work for Oracle.  Oracle has more akward stuff that makes me assume that they never hired any golf-coder.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that, in my specific case, I would have to write more logic in the backend, and I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: So it must return a string then? Oh well, that's easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `concat()` to begin with?

Assuming Hibernate takes care of converting the non-standard `year()`, `month()` and `day()` functions, then the following should work on any DBMS

```
SELECT year(tx.date_), month(tx.date_), day(tx.date_), iss.code 
FROM tx_ tx 
  JOIN issuer_ iss ON tx.id_issuer = iss.id  
GROUP BY year(tx.date_), month(tx.date_), day(tx.date_), iss.code
```

Comment: Sorry, totally my fault. I didn't say it, but I'm making a **count to know the number of tx made by issuer and day**. I'm gonna edit my question right now.

Besides, The reason I'm using the concat is because I'm going to store that date in another table, and I don't want to write more logic in backend (I think is more efficient if Hibernate makes the concat for me).

Comment: @sunday: even then, I think the concat is the wrong approach. You have three values, keep them in three columns. Or - if possible - cast the column to a proper `DATE` but I don't know if that is possible with your obfuscation layer